# In Qt3D, when adding components to an Entity using ID, what happens?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

Fake Edit: Sorry about the weird title. Not sure yet how to phrase this question

Context: Working through this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-multiviewport-example.html , this file: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-multiviewport-main-qml.html

Here's a sparse version of the QML I'm looking at:

```
Entity {
    id: rootNode

    CameraLens {
        id: cameraLens
        ...
    }

    Entity {
            id: cameraViewport1
            property Transform transform : Transform {
                ...
            }
            components: [cameraLens, transform]
    }

    Entity {
            id: cameraViewport2
            property Transform transform : Transform {
                ...
            }
            components: [cameraLens, transform]
    }
}
```

So I've got these questions:

1- 
How is the ID search performed? Presumably, it checks the local context first (so the `transform` referenced in `cameraViewport1` is found instead of the one in `cameraViewport2`), and the proceeds up the tree (which would be how it finds the `cameraLens` component), but I haven't been able to find documentation that confirms or explains this.

2-
Is there only one `cameraLens` that is shared by both `cameraViewport` entities? As in, if I access and change the `cameraLens` through `cameraViewport1`, do those changes effect `cameraViewport2`? Basically, it is "passed" by value, or by reference?

I may have simply been unable to find the documentation; if so, links are good, links with explanations as to how to find them are better! (there's more I haven't been able to find docs on)

Comment: Yes and yes. These are both generic QML questions actually and not Qt3d-specific, did you check the existing QML documentation?

Comment: I'm coming at QT/QML fresh through Qt3D, so no, but I'll go look now. I have very little idea about "what's new" going from Qt to Qt3D, but in retrospect, that seems like it would definitely not be one of them. Thanks!